# ActiveModel Serializers changing output for associated models' parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

this is what the serializer for `Event` looks like now

```
class EventSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :venue, :artists
end
```

the output I get is

```
[{"name":"Dance your ass off",
  "venue":{"id":21,"name":"Speakeasy","address":"Lynwood Ave","zip_code":30312,"created_at":"2016-03-24T18:13:03.032Z","updated_at":"2016-03-24T18:13:03.032Z"},
  "artists":[{"id":41,"name":"DJ Sliink","bio":"jersey club king","created_at":"2016-03-24T18:13:03.067Z","updated_at":"2016-03-24T18:13:03.067Z"},{"id":42,"name":"DJ Spinn","bio":"Teklife's chief spokesperson","created_at":"2016-03-24T18:13:03.072Z","updated_at":"2016-03-24T18:13:03.072Z"}]}]
```

how do I change this to showing just the names of `venue` and `artists`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom methods for those required attributes as shown below:

```
class EventSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :venue, :artists

  def name
     object.name
  end

  def venue
     object.venue.name
  end

  def artists
     object.artists.map(&:name)
  end
end
```

You can refer the AMS [docs](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/master/docs) for further information.